# Create External Content Type in SP Online without SP Designer

Tags: sharepoint-online, external-content-type

I would like to create an External Content Type (ECT) inside SharePoint Online to connect to an Azure SQL Database.

I cannot use SP Designer, what options do I have to create an ECT on a Macbook?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot create external content type by SharePoint designer, you could create external content type by visual studio.

Then you could follow the steps below to create external content type:

1. Set permissions on the BCS Metadata Store.
2. Create a Secure Store Mapping.
3. Create an External Content Type (ECT) by visual studio.
4. Create an External List.
5. Grant permissions to manage your ECT.

For more detailed information, refer to the articles below.

[Make an External List from a SQL Azure table with Business Connectivity Services and Secure Store.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/make-external-list)

[How to create an “External Content Type” using Visual Studio 2012 for SharePoint 2013 Online and OData.](https://collab365.community/external-content-type-and-sharepoint-online-bcs-with-odata/)

[Create an OData data service for use as a BCS external system on SharePoint Online.](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepointdevelopersupport/2018/08/02/create-an-odata-data-service-for-use-as-a-bcs-external-system-on-sharepoint-online/)

updated:

I suggest you could create external content type by SharePoint designer.

The most are the same for creating external content type in visual studio 2012 and visual studio 2019.

Comment: Thanks, however a lot of these links seem really old. For example, it's 2019 and this article references VS 2012? Do you know of any newer links? Secondly, this doesn't quite answer the question on how this works on a Macbook? (e.g. can you even install Visual Studio on a Mac and it works?)...

Comment: Lastly, it seems restrictive from Microsoft to only allow ECT's to be created from SharePoint Designer (which is being discontinued) and Visual Studio..with the advent of SPFx, surely it could be done via that model or via a UI configuration.

Comment: I have updated my reply.

Comment: Hey Amy, not sure if you read the original question but I said I cannot use SP Designer....do you know if Visual Studio for Mac is capable of doing the same as VS for Windows? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

BCS Meta Man can help. Using the BCS Meta Man application, you can configure an External Content Type for SQL Azure, and OData services. This approach helps you to build all required methods, actions, associations, filters etc without needing to write any code:

https://lightningtools.com/product/bcs-meta-man-windows

Brett